# Is there any significant difference between DSL and Fiber connection?

Tags: download, isp, upload, internet-speed

I read many internet articles stating that people usually are not getting full internet speeds they are advertised to because ISPs advertise their packages as an *up to*, so if someone subscribed to 10mbps plan, then he might be getting 80% or less for his internet speeds which is still considered normal on DSL.

I have 10mbps and 1mbps, but on speedtest I get about 9.6mbps and 0.97mbps which i think is normal.

However, my main question here is, is it exactly the same thing for Fiber? If I subscirbed to Fiber internet plan, will I still not get the advertised speeds that I am paying for even on Fiber?

Comment: It always depends on the fine print of your contract. There are both DSL and fiber packages that have guaranteed minimum bandwidths (most of the time propagated as "business packages") - and packages without such a thing. In the EU, providers have to provide a certain minimum of the propagated bandwidth at all times (as far as I recall; perhaps it was "per 24 hours" instead). **Conclusion:** Fiber (or the absence of it) has nothing to do with what your provider can (or cannot) state: you have to check your country's regulations and/or the fine print of the contract.

Comment: According to my ISP page, it says *up to* 200mbps fiber, so does that mean whether it is DSL or Fiber, it is impossible to get the full advertised internet speeds in any country?

Comment: Nope - it means that in the best of cases, you will have 200 Mb/s - and not a single bit/s more. It does not state what your worst case could be - in the EU, as I said, it was around 60% of the propagated bandwidth at all times (*again: so I think. I cannot find a decent, English article to support this claim, though in my country, I know of some people that successfully sued for their minimum bandwidth because of that regulation.*) - that's what regulations are for. However, it is **not impossible** to get the maximum bandwidth - if you're extremely lucky, you could even have it all the time.

Comment: Yes I understand that completely. I know that you could theoretically hit maximum speed, but back in DSL days, people used to get lower speeds despite being advertised to speeds higher than what they would normally get. However, just out of curiosity, does Fiber has exactly same story where someone might actually get lower than advertised? Like, is it really normal to get 48mbps on 50mbps plan? Just like how i am getting 9mbps on 10mbps plan? Or is guaranteed speed on Fiber?

Comment: See my other two comments as this would just be a repetition of all that I stated earlier. I can, however, add my own story to that: [This is the chart from my last few speedtests](https://imgur.com/a/s4Few) - I have fiber-package with a propagated maximum down-speed of 80 Mb/s and 7.5 Mb/s up-speed. I live in the capital of my country, which, as stated, has laws that require the provider to at least provide me with 60 or so percent of the maximum bandwidth. *(A regulation that would make no sense if it wasn't an issue)*

Comment: ADSL speed is primarily dependent on the (wire) distance from the CO.  Since the ISP doesn't know in advance how much copper wire is involved, it can only advertise a top rate, not the rate you would actually get.  Fiber in comparison to copper has very low signal loss due to distance, so your distance from the CO is not significant.  Another difference is that fiber is much faster than ADSL.

Comment: @sawdust Its maximum bit rate (from a technical standpoint, not from consumer standpoint) is higher, but it doesn't necessarily *need* to be faster - again, it depends on your contract. But of course you are correct in saying that fiber is a bit more resilient in terms of attenuation - that argument somehow slipped my mind...

Answer (score 0):

This question cannot be answered without knowing exactly what the contract looks like and which country you live in (and its regulations), as it all depends on those two things.

The maximum bandwidth is just an artificial limit pushed by the provider.
The minimum bandwidth is something that must be stated in some countries - if it isn't specified and there is no regulation in your coutry that says something like "In a 24h time frame, the average bandwidth must not drop below xx% of the specified maximum bandwidth", then you could get everything from 0,1 to 100% of the bandwidth at any time.

The current bandwidth depends on the infrastructure (how well was it installed: loose, cheaply crimped connectors, cheap cables, water in the fiber cable's conduit, old modems,... it all adds up) and on how much it is used at any time: that's why most people have the worst bandwidth in the evening (most people are home and do things on the internet) and the best bandwidth in the early morning (noone is awake yet to use the internet).

There is no real rule of thumb concerning the difference of DSL and fiber rearding minimum bandwidths: I know of people in my town (the capital of my country) with the exact same provider and product that sometimes have very low bandwidth results, while I'm generally happy (after exchanging the modem).

So your best bet is to either try it out or look for a provider that offers you a guaranteed minimum bandwidth - DSL and fiber, however, will only be a concern as far as maximum speeds are concerned. None of them can give a guarantee for better bandwidths per se.